# Algorithm to describe attack range in an tile-based game

Tags: algorithm

We are currently developing a tile-based and turn-based game. In our game, there are characters that can attack others from afar. However, the attack range seems a little bit hard to describe using algorithms. It is illustrated below, every number indicates the range between the tile '0' and itself.

```
5 4 3 3 3 4 5 
4 3 2 2 2 3 4
3 2 1 1 1 2 3
3 2 1 0 1 2 3
3 2 1 1 1 2 3
4 3 2 2 2 3 4
5 4 3 3 3 4 5
```

Is it possible to implement a function like this?

`int GetRange( const Grid & a, const Grid & b );`

Comment: Is the range limited to this square, or can it be greater too? If so, can you provide a larger example please?

Comment: [Distance in a Cartesian coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Distance_between_two_points)

Comment: @zapl, it isn't the Euclidean distance that the OP wants

Comment: @Vilx-, This example is greater enough actually, because there're not many tiles in our game. So we currently implement it by hard code these tiles :P

Comment: @ronalchn true if OP wants exactly that distance mapping. Rounded euclidian distance would be quite similar though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only 3 possible cases need to be dealt with:

- when the points are on the same horizontal line,
- on the same vertical line,
- all other cases

In C++:

```c++
int GetRange( const Grid & a, const Grid & b ) {
  int x=a.x-b.x, y=a.y-b.y; // get change in x & y coordinates
  if (x==0) return abs(y);
  if (y==0) return abs(x);
  else return (abs(x)+abs(y)-1);
}
```

Comment: Good one! That indeed produces the result the OP demonstrated. I just wonder if this is what is needed for larger ranges too. Hopefully the OP will elaborate.